# Why is the Dirac Delta considered a distribution?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Everywhere it is specified (with good reason, since no such function could be defined) that the Dirac Delta function $\delta(x)$ is not a function, but a distribution.

I know that distributions are defined as continuous linear functionals $F[\varphi]$ acting on the space of test functions $F: T \to \Bbb{R} $, therefore distributions belong to its dual space $T^*$. Such functionals can be represented as integrals: $F = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(t)\varphi(t)}dt $ where $f(t)$ is some function integrable on $\varphi$'s support.

In the Delta case, if we define the functional $\delta_{t_0}[\varphi]:= \varphi(t_0)$, no such $f$ can be found (except in a limit process of delta-approximating bump function), but we still define this hypotetic delta function as $\delta(t-t_0)$ implying that it only makes sense when it is inside an integral, in the same way (correct me if i'm wrong) as it is customary to write $P.V. (\frac{1}{x})$ inside some equation, without integration, knowing it will make sense (Cauchy's P.V.) once it is integrated.

So, why everywhere $\delta(t-t_0)$ (or Heaviside step, or anything else in that situation) is called a distribution? The functional $\delta_{t_0}(\varphi) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\delta(t-t_0)\varphi(t)}dt $ should be the distribution, not its integral's kernel ($\delta_{t_0} \in T^*$ is in the space of distributions).

Could someone explain me the situation better?

Comment: Only some functionals can be represented by a $f.$

Comment: Sure, and i know $\delta(t)$ is not one of them, but my question was different: why is delta function the one called distribution, and not it's related fucntional $\delta_{t_0}$? Schwartz Distribution should be the functionals, not their representative (functions or whatever strange object are...)

Comment: It's simply terminology. Functionals are associated to their respective integral kernels, so there isn't much harm in the abuse of terminology.

Comment: I thought it was just abuse of terminology, but since I am studying this stuff for an exam in mathematical methods for physics, it confused me, and I wanted to make things clear. Thanks for the help.